# Compare memory footprint of alternative implementations

Tags: .net, xml, memory

I need to compare two xml documents, and want to figure out at what data size XmlReader starts to yield significant size benefits compared to XmlDocument/XDocument.

In my naivity, I thought I could simply run my simple test console, which compares the contents of two XML files using two different implementatinons (one based on XmlDocument, the other on XmlReader), while profiling with a tool.

I tried using CLR Profiler 4, a free tool from the Performance Architect of the CLR, but it gave me exactly no information at all. Then I downloaded a trial of ANTS Profiler, but this too gave me nothing at all!

My test file ATM is fairly small and the program just blazes through both files and then exits. It is implemented as a console, if this matters. I can't fathom why I get "there are no results to display" from ANTS and "0 bytes allocated" from CLR Profiler - both seem to show me just "live" results, but I want to run the code, and analyze what happened afterwards.

Is there a simple way I can figure this out? Does perhaps the GC or related types expose functionality that makes it possible? I am primarily interested in total memory used, though it would also be of interest to see if any large objects (> 80KB and hence not "defragmentable") are created.

--

Please refrain from boilerplate "XmlReader is smaller" or "XmlReader has a flat footprint" responses. I am aware of this. But I need to establish the size of the gains and at what data size it becomes significant in order to actually choose between them. Just knowing that XmlReader will "at some point" be "significantly smaller" simply isn't good enough.

Comment: First of all, make sure you are using the programs correctly. Memory profilers normally require you to take a snapshot. That's the time it gathers all information for you to see.

Answer (score 1):

With memory profiler you usually take 2 snapshots, before and after interesting event and then compare them to see memory usage and leaks. So you can add some Console.Read() to your app before parsing and after (but before releasing all resources), take snapshoots at these moments and compare them. But if you just need to see memory usage then I think you can do it just with Task Manager or Process Explorer.

Samples:
[image]

Comment: Task Manager/Process explorer may give ballpark ideas about memory usage, but strictly speaking they only say something about how unmanaged memory is used. I don't know very much about how the CLR manages memory, but I know it does manage memory. It will, for example, allocate more native memory than it needs to fulfill a small managed memory allocation. Similarly it might release memory according to its own ideas and not directly whenever managed memory is freed. But most important, such "profiling" is just nowhere near detailed enough to give any insight into WHY things are the way they are.

Comment: I agree about Task Manager, but modern process explorer shows many information about clr proccesses and memory usage. Take a look at screenshot I added to my answer.